# How to access the model's description in CoreML?

Tags: swift, coreml, coremltools

I have a CoreML model and I've added information to the model using coremltools:

```
model.author = 'Vincent Garcia'
model.license = 'BSD'
model.short_description = 'The model is doing something.'
```

Is there a way to access this information from Swift?

On Apple's documentation, it's written:

> Inspect your model’s metadata and MLFeatureDescription instances
> through modelDescription.

I tried this:

```swift
let model = try! MyModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
let desc = model.modelDescription
```

but I got the following error:

> Value of type 'MyModel' has no member 'modelDescription'

It seems that I'm not using the documentation properly.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyModel` is not an `MLModel` object but a class that is specifically generated for your model. However, it does have an `MLModel` object inside, in the `model` property.

You can access the description like so:

```
let model = try! MyModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
let desc = model.model.modelDescription
```